# French chars from imported file are not showing correctly in IE

Tags: html, csv, internet-explorer, input

I'm importing a csv file containing french chars through an input file element of a web page:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >

<input type='file' id='selectedFile' name='selectedFile'  accept='text/csv'/>
```

The file is exported from excel with the format UTF-8 CSV.

The content is sent to a server and parsed by a java method. The french chars are not showing correctly in IE. The chars are correctly displayed in any other browser.

Example: Aéroport CDG is displayed as AÃ©roport CDG

Comment: is the whole site in french or just a bit? If it's the whole site, you should really set the hreflang in the head e.g.  hreflang="fr" (if it's just one div or so, you can still set the language e.g. <div lang="fr"> etc..

Comment: The problem only occurs when the file encoding format is not UTF-8. Please open the imported csv file with Notepad to check the file encoding and you can try to save the file as encoding UTF-8 in Notepad. Then try again in IE. The UTF-8 CSV file shows correctly in my IE11.